# Cucumber leaf damage, what is it?

Tags: identification, damage, cucumbers

I am in Florida. I noticed this, and it seems to be getting worse, what is it, and can you please tell me how to fix it, thanks[image]

Answer (score 1):

This could be a downy mildew infection. I’m not a 100% sure though.

[image: Downy Mildew Infection]

[I'd give this website a visit if you're looking for a treatment](https://www.seminis-us.com/resources/agronomic-spotlights/managing-downy-mildew-in-cucumbers/)